# magento2 add credit memo for invoice with items

Tags: magento2, creditmemo

I am trying to add partial credit memo programatically but it is consuming whole quantity in first credit memo, How can I pass specific items to credit memo?

```
public function createCreditMemo ($entityId,$invId,$shipping,$subtotal,$grandtotal,$tax) {

        $post_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $itemsArray = array();

        foreach($post_data['items'] as $index => $details){ 
                 $quantity = $details['qty'];           
         $order_item_id = $details['order_item_id'];
                 $itemsArray[$order_item_id]=$quantity; 
            }

        $orderId = $entityId; 
        $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderId);    
        $shippingAmount = $shipping;
        $subTotal = $subtotal;
        $taxAmount = $tax;
        $grandTotal = $grandtotal;
        $invoiceId = $invId;

        $invoiceobj =  $this->invoice->load($invId);
        $creditmemo = $this->creditmemoFactory->createByInvoice($invoiceobj,$itemsArray);

        $creditmemo->setShippingAmount($shippingAmount);
        $creditmemo->setTaxAmount($taxAmount);
        $creditmemo->setBaseTaxAmount($taxAmount);
        $creditmemo->setSubtotal($subTotal);
        $creditmemo->setBaseSubtotal($subTotal);
        $creditmemo->setGrandTotal($grandTotal);
        $creditmemo->setBaseGrandTotal($grandTotal);

        $this->creditmemoService->refund($creditmemo);

       return $creditmemo->getId();




    }
}
```

I am passing item array still it is taking all the items of invoice.

Comment: You can check the native adminhtml flow here : `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Creditmemo/Save.php`

Answer (score 0):

replace of your code line from :

```
$creditmemo = $this->creditmemoFactory->createByInvoice($invoiceobj,$itemsArray);
```

to

```
$creditmemo = $this->creditmemoFactory->createByOrder($order,$itemsArray);
```

Comment: Now it is taking full ordered quantity.

Comment: do you verify that, you get proper data into $itemsArray?

Comment: Yes, I am sending only one item I have verified that. Is there any specific form of array required?